# Код считывает, но не работает со строчкой

Tags: java, строки

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class getEncrypt {
public String getEncryptMethod(String in){
    String fileName = "lib.txt";
    String str;
    String[] phasa1;
    String[] phasa2;
    String cryptedNames = "Ошибка";

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            str = sc.nextLine();
            phasa1 = str.split("=");
            phasa2 = phasa1[0].split(",");
            for (String i : phasa2) {
                if (i.equalsIgnoreCase(in)){
                    cryptedNames = phasa1[1];
                    return phasa1[1];
                }
                else cryptedNames = "Ошибка.";
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println();
    }
    return cryptedNames;
}
}
```

Вот часть той самой lib.txt:

```
 УУУ,УУЦ=Фенилаланин
 УУА,УУГ,ЦУУ,ЦУЦ,ЦУА,ЦУГ=Лейцин
```

И всё кроме УУУ прекрасно преобразовывает.

Comment: Что значит "не работает со строчкой"? Что этот код должен делать? Что делает не так? Опишите проблему подробнее.

Comment: Я ввожу зашифрованый код РНК(немного биологии), а он по библиотеке должен найти его, и выдать уже расшифрованный.

Comment: И что не работает?

Comment: И судя по тексту вопроса, на ввод "УУГ" программа выдаёт "Лейцин", а на ввод "УУУ" выдаёт "Ошибка."?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, да верно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На все 100% уверен, что файл lib.txt сохранён в кодировке UTF-8 с BOM. Пересохраните в UTF-8 без BOM и всё будет в порядке. Или добавьте операцию удаления BOM в код:

```
str = sc.nextLine();
str = str.replace("\uFEFF", "");
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, но как это работает? Как вы это поняли?

Comment: Что такое BOM и зачем оно можно почитать [здесь](https://goo.gl/SfFLFB). В вашей программе получается, что после разбития строки по символу равенства и запятым, первый элемент содержит не "УУУ", а "\uFEFFУУУ". Редакторы BOM не отображают, но Java в сравнении строк учитывает. А понял я это потому, что за 17 лет работы успел наступить на очень большое количество граблей :)

Answer (score 1):

кстати говоря
может кому и пригодится
в IIDEA можно избавиться от BOM
правый клик на файле и
выбрать remove BOM